# Thread a sub with two arguments?

Tags: c#, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [thread with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831009/thread-with-multiple-parameters)

How does one thread a sub with two arguments?

I want to thread my sub like so but its coming up with errors:

```
Thread t = new Thread (subname);
t.Start()
```

Here are the errors:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to
>   'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart'
>
> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Here is how my sub looks:

```
    public string send2(string kom, string ddm)
        {

///code for a httpwebrequest (too long to post all of it)


}
```

Do you guys have any solutions?

Comment: What parameter values do you expect your sub to be invoked with? This does not make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a lambda:

```
...
string kom = ...
string ddm = ...

Thread t = new Thread( () => send2( kom, ddm ) );
```

Comment: So if the strings kom and ddm are declared or specified in the webrequest can I make them null so when the thread starts they wont be null anymore?

Comment: As I explained in my answer, I am concerned about thread-safety issues in case the strings are modified immediately after starting the thread.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I would like to point your attention to the following scenario:

```
...
string kom = ...
string ddm = ...

Thread t = new Thread( () => send2( kom, ddm ) );

t.start();
// the strings get assigned different values
kom = ...
ddm = ...
```

It may not be your case, but it can happen, so it's a good idea to be aware of it.

If the two strings get assigned different values before `t` has a chance to start, then the method `send2` will get the new values of the strings and **not the values that they had when the thread was created**.

In this case it's a better idea to copy the strings inside a wrapper object and pass the to the thread as parameter:

```
Wrapper w = new Wrapper(); // contains two strings
w.String1 = String.Copy(kom);
w.String2 = String.Copy(ddm);

Thread t = new Thread( 
    o => 
    {
        Wrapper lw = (Wrapper)o;
        send2( lw.String1, lw.String2 ) );
    });

t.start(w);
// the strings get assigned different values
kom = ...
ddm = ...
```

Now you are truly safe, because the strings got copied and passed to the thread, so subsequent modifications cannot affect the execution of the thread.