# C# : thread that accepts tree object parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [thread with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831009/thread-with-multiple-parameters)

i know how to call a thread with 1 object by using the following code :

```
                Thread t = new Thread(o => { CALL((string)o); });
                t.Start(i.ToString());
```

But what if i want to call a method that takes 3 object parameters ?
How to do that ?

Comment: Never mind , found answer here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831009/thread-with-multiple-parameters

Comment: deleted my answer, as the array hint is in the other SO as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the `new object[] { param1, param2, ... , paramN }` as an object.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, besides an array, you can pass a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383822.aspx). A bit more strong typed, at least for what the values are concerned.